# Checkbox Command Not Firing When Initially Unchecked

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, command, checkbox

I have a column of checkboxes in a datagrid.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn CanUserResize="False" Header="" Width="auto">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Style="{StaticResource CheckBoxSelectTypeStyle}" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Selected}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I have a command bound to unchecking and checking.

```
<Style x:Key="CheckBoxSelectTypeStyle" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding DataContext.CheckedCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" />
            <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding Path=SelectedItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding DataContext.UncheckedCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" />
            <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding Path=SelectedItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

My problem is that if the checkboxes start as unchecked and you check one, then no commands are fired (This is the problem). If you then uncheck the same checkbox, the uncheck command will fire (As expected). If you then check the same checkbox again, the check command will fire (As expected). Everything will work fine for that checkbox at that point, but the others still have the same problem.

If a checkbox starts as checked it will work fine. My question is how do I make the command fire when the checkbox starts as unchecked. I can't find any reason for it not to work.

**Response to suggestion:**

I tried to add a trigger for `Null`, but it has the exact same problem, nothing changed.

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding DataContext.CheckedCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" />
        <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding Path=SelectedItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding DataContext.UncheckedCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" />
        <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding Path=SelectedItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="{x:Null}">
        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding DataContext.UncheckedCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" />
        <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding Path=SelectedItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

**ViewModel Code**

```
public ICommand CheckedCommand { get; set; }
public ICommand UncheckedCommand { get; set; }
```

---

```
CheckedCommand = new RelayCommand<IList>(Checked);
UncheckedCommand = new RelayCommand<IList>(Unchecked);
```

---

```
private void Checked(IList selectedItems)
{
    ChangedChecked(selectedItems, true);
}

private void Unchecked(IList selectedItems)
{
    ChangedChecked(selectedItems, false);
}

private void ChangedChecked(IList selectedItems, bool selected)
{
    if (selectedItems.HasValue())
        foreach (var item in selectedItems)
            if(item is SelectedTypeModel) (item as SelectedTypeModel).Selected = selected;
}
```

RelayCommand implements ICommand. As I mentioned before, the `Checked` method is not called when the checkbox starts as unchecked, but it *is* called when it is checked, unchecked, and checked again or if it starts checked and is unchecked.

**What I'm Trying To Do**

I have a DataGrid with a column of CheckBoxs. I want to be able to highlight multiple rows, then check/uncheck a CheckBox in one of the selected rows and have all the other rows update to be the same. I also have a keyword filter for the datagrid, so the DataGrid is binding to a ListCollectionView.

**Output Information**

I enabled debug information for data binding and get this message:

> System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=Selected; DataItem=null; target element is 'CheckBox' (Name=''); target property is 'IsChecked' (type 'Nullable`1')

I'm still not sure how to use this information to correct the problem though.

**SOLUTION**

I did not fix my original problem and I still don't know why it doesn't work correctly, but I have used another method with the same desired result. Here is the changed code:

```
<Style x:Key="CheckBoxSelectTypeStyle" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding DataContext.CheckedChangedCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" />
    <Setter Property="CommandParameter">
        <Setter.Value>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource SelectedItemsCheckedMultiValueConverter}">
                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}" Path="SelectedItems"/>
                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="IsChecked"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

---

```
public ICommand CheckedChangedCommand { get; set; }
```

---

```
CheckedChangedCommand = new RelayCommand<Tuple<IList, bool>>(CheckedChanged);
```

Comment: Please post the `eventhandler` code for the [`Checkbox.CheckChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.checkedchanged.aspx) event.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding you, but I don't have an event handler for CheckChanged. There is no code behind in the View. It should be calling a Command in the ViewModel, and it does except for the first check when it starts as unchecked. I don't even see a CheckChanged event for a CheckBox in WPF; only Checked and Unchecked events.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified that first.  I am not well-versed enough in `WPF` to be helpful in this issue :(

Comment: IsChecked is a [Nullable Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/2cf62fcy(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: Please post the relevant code from your ViewModel (command property and handler). I tried to reproduce this in a new application and the command fires off.

Comment: Another suggestion would be to pass the IsChecked property in the CommandParameter and access the selected items in another way (perhaps bind SelectedItems to a property in your viewmodel). Then you would have a single command and not have to worry about the triggers.

Comment: Actually, testing my little app has revealed that the command gets fired off on being checked, but not unchecked. I have no clue why...voted up the question to see if someone else knows

Comment: I have already tried binding the SelectedItems to the ViewModel, but I was unable to because it is Read-Only, so I don't know of a way to do that. I know the ViewModel would only be reading it, but I couldn't find a way to get past the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**
I think you can achieve your goals without any need in triggers (I've tested this solution in small sample app):
so your style would looks like this:

```
<Style x:Key="CheckBoxSelectTypeStyle" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding DataContext.CheckedCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" />
    <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding Path=SelectedItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />
  ...
```

There will be only one command in your view model. And as parameter that command will receive list of selected items. So only one thing is missing - whether user is about to check or uncheck checkbox. At the moment I can think of one possible way of passing this info along with SelectedItems - write MultiBinding with custom converter which will put selectedItems and current value of IsChecked in something like Tuple<..., bool>

```
        <Setter Property="CommandParameter">
            <Setter.Value>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{x:Static PackTupleConverter.Instance}">
                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}" Path="SelectedItems"/>
                    <Binding RelativeSource="{x:Static RelativeSource.Self}" Path="IsChecked"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
```

**end**

I was able to repro your problem by simply putting same checkbox inside ListBox. Once that done first time I click on checkbox - command don't get called

here is sample window xaml:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="CheckBoxSelectTypeStyle" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding DataContext.Test, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding DataContext.Test, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ListBox>
        <ListBox.Items>
            <CheckBox Style="{StaticResource CheckBoxSelectTypeStyle}" />
        </ListBox.Items>
    </ListBox>

</Grid>
```

and sode behaind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        Test = new DelegateCommand(TestCommand);
    }

    public ICommand Test { get; set; }

    private void TestCommand()
    {
    }
}
```

Here is what I've discovered in output regarding binding:

> System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.Test; DataItem=null; target element is 'CheckBox' (Name=''); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')

Comment: I just looked at it and I don't see anything that stands out. I don't see any errors. Thanks for your suggestion though.

Comment: Have you turned on information messages for "WPF Trace Settings section" \ "Data Binding"?

Comment: Can you describe briefly what are you trying to achieve? Because in general it's not a good idea to use RelativeSource inside items in ItemsControl derivatives (in cases when to trying to get some controls outside the ItemsControl).

Comment: I updated my question at the end with what I'm trying to do. I am relatively new to using commands in XAML, so I don't fully understand what I should and shouldn't be using. Any help is appreciated. I don't think I have information messages turned on, so I'll look into that and see if I get the same message as you did in your example.

Comment: I enabled the data binding information and I get the same message as you. I'm still not sure how to fix the problem though.

Comment: I think your solution will work, but I'll have to finish implementing it tomorrow. I'll mark it as the solution then if it works. Thanks.

Comment: Your solution worked. I would vote it up, but I don't have enough reputation.